# Java method scope not finding symbol?

Tags: java

I am wondering why this code doesn't work(gives me error saying cannot find symbol and points to the while loop). Where as if I move the boolean variable 'sequirloop outside the do while loop it will work.

```
//Metodo seleccion de modo
public void SeleccionDeModo()
{
    do
    {
    //Permite al usuario seleccionar metodo de escucha
    System.out.println("Seleccione metodo de escucha:");
    System.out.println("0 = Secuencia normal");
    System.out.println("1 = Reproduccion aleatoria");

            //variables necesarias
    int unoCero = scanner.nextInt();
    boolean seguirLoop = true;

    //Selecciona una opcion
        switch (unoCero)
        {
        case 0:
        System.out.println("Selecciono reproduccion secuencial:");
        seguirLoop = false;
        break;

        case 1:
        System.out.println("Selecciono reproduccion aleatoria:");
        seguirLoop = false;
        break;

        default:
                    System.out.println("Ingrese un valor sugerido!");
        seguirLoop = true;
        break;
        }
//here in the next line!!!
    }while( seguirLoop == true );

}
```

Comment: `seguirLoop` has to be defined in a higher scope than the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The Boolean variable is in a lower scope than the do loop, therefore the while loop cannot see it. I suggest you look into Java variable scopes. Putting the variable outside of the loop will make the scope higher.